# What is the problem with my negamax implementation?

Tags: engines, programming

I am currently attempting to make a basic chess engine in Python (Learning some basic concepts), but for some reason the engine is suicidal and does not detect the scholars mate. I am using python-chess for the board because I am lazy, but I think the issue is my implementation of negamax? I've read on chessprogramming wiki but still can't figure out the issue.

Here is the code on GitHub: https://github.com/AggressiveBee15/LousyEngine

Comment: Why do I need to add a negative sign? Sorry I don't really understand negamax yet (I was doing separate subroutines before I switched)

Comment: If `score >= beta`, you should return the score, not beta.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't detect checkmate.

Comment: For the negative sign before the initial call, wikipedia seems to say that a negative sign isn't required before the root negamax call.

Comment: Try to add a check for checkmate, and run again. Also post the outputs.

Comment: The [community has decided](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/418/7297) that questions about chess programming are **on-topic**. This is also stated in the [help center](/help/on-topic): *Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome.*

Comment: That said, this question should be reduced to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as soon as possible; questions should not depend on external links which may break.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think the question is on-topic. But if it drags on with code-level assistance, it's off-topic. In my answer, I gave general advice but actually running the code is off-topic.

Comment: @Glorfindel OP was asking for code-level assistance in the comments to my answer. I don't see how we can possibility answer the question unless it's edited.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Lacking an MCVE is also an off-topic reason. I think one should resort to a custom off-topic reason in those cases, because just saying it's not in scope doesn't help the OP. See also [this Meta question](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/491/7297).

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question to fit the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't run your code, but by just looking:

- You should return the score when `score >= beta`. This is consistent to Wikipedia:

[image]

Note when alpha >= beta, Wikipedia returns the score, not beta.

- Your code doesn't detect checkmate? I don't see how your engine can report Scholar mate without detecting checkmate.
- Minor issue. The condition should be `>=` not `>`, but that shouldn't change anything.
- What outputs did you get from: `print('New good move ...`?

Comment: Previously, when I used my minimal implementation, the engine could prevent simple checkmates. Coincidence???

Comment: @AggresiveBee15 I don't know about your previous implementation, but I don't see how your engine would work if you don't check for end of game by checkmate.

Comment: Where would I add the checkmate check? Should I add the check right after the move is pushed?

Comment: In evaluation, if the position is checkmate your evaluator must return infinity.

Comment: Also, currently I run the engine with the depth of 3. The game went: 1. e4 a5 2. d4 b5 3. Bxb5  Why did it blunder a pawn? The evaluation function is really basic, but should be able to calculate the material loss.

Comment: @AggresiveBee15 I don't know! Can you please post your sample outputs?